# Comparing a reaction to an emoji returns false even though its the same emoji

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to discord.py, and I can't get this to work, I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find an answer.

What I want to do: User gets a role if they react with a specific emoji and gets another role when they react with another emoji.

What happens: No roles are given.

Here's my code

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = bot.get_channel(780094535711719465)

    if user == bot.user:
        return

    print("Reaction detected") #DEBUG
    print(reaction) #DEBUG. Returns  or  respectively
    print(user) #DEBUG. Returns whoever reacted
    print(reaction == "") #DEBUG. Returns False always
    print(reaction == "}") #DEBUG. Returns False always

    if reaction == "\N{TABLE TENNIS PADDLE AND BALL}": #Using "" also returns False
        print("Detected tennis padle") #DEBUG
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="test")
        await user.add_roles(Role)
        print("Added test role") #DEBUG

    elif reaction == "\N{RUNNER}": #Using "" also returns false
        print("Detected runner") #DEBUG
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="test2")
        await user.add_roles(Role)
        print("Added test2 role") #DEBUG
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you get if you `print(type(reaction))` and `print(len(reaction))`? I'm expecting `string` and `1`.

Comment: Hi @RyanH. `print(type(reaction))` returns `<class 'discord.reaction.Reaction'>` and `print(len(reaction))` returns `TypeError: object of type 'Reaction' has no len()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `reaction` is an object of type `discord.reaction.Reaction` you can't compare it to a string. You need to access the emoji string from the object, so it might be something like this:

```
if reaction["emoji"]["name"] == "":
```

Perhaps the section on [Awaiting reactions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions) in the Discord.js documentation might be helpful.

(I realize that you are programming in Python so you'll need to figure out the exact Python syntax)